# Repopulate Textbox in PartialView When Page Fails Validation

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a View that besides being bound to a model, has 3 partial views (a people picker) of a reuseable component. I perform a validation to check for duplicates of the data in the model at submit. If the record is a dup, it redirects back to the page, where the model can repopulate the model fields. However, I'd like the People Picker values to be retained as well, but since it is not part of the model, I don't know how to do that.

This is the controller

```
  public ActionResult Create(IFormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            Dept_COEModel Dept = new DeptModel();
            Dept.DeptName = collection["DeptName"];
            Dept.DeptAcronym = collection["DeptAcronym"];
            Dept.DeptCeNtId = collection["UserIdHidden_20"];
            Dept.DeptCeUserName = collection["UserNameHidden_20"];
            Dept.DeptCeEmail = collection["UserEmailHidden_20"];


            Dept.delegate1PocNtId = collection["UserIdHidden_30"];
            Dept.delegate1PocName = collection["UserNameHidden_30"];
            Dept.delegate1PocEmail = collection["UserEmailHidden_30"];


            Dept.delegate2PocNtId = collection["UserIdHidden_40"];
            Dept.delegate2PocName = collection["UserNameHidden_40"];
            Dept.delegate2PocEmail = collection["UserEmailHidden_40"];


            int result = _adoSqlService.CheckDept(collection["DeptName"]);

            if (result == 0)
            {
                _adoSqlService.InsertDept(dept);
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));

            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("DeptName", "This Department already exists");
                ViewData["UserResultTextbox_20"] = Dept.DeptCeUserName;
                return View(Dept);
            }


        }
        catch
        {
            return View(Dept);
        }

    }
```

Here is the View

```
@model EDAD.Models.LOB_COEModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>LOB_COE</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            @*<div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="lobCoeId" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="lobCoeId" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="lobCoeId" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>*@
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="lobCoeName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="lobCoeName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="lobCoeName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="lobCoeAcronym" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="lobCoeAcronym" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="lobCoeAcronym" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Select Chief Engineer</label>
                <div class="form-group form-field-div">
                    <table>
                        <tr style="white-space:nowrap;">
                            <td>
                                @Html.Action("PeoplePicker", "PeoplePicker", new EDAD.Models.PeoplePickerViewModel { PickerId = 20 })
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

                @*<span asp-validation-for="lobCoeCeNtId" class="text-danger"></span>*@
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Select Delegate 1</label>
                <div class="form-group form-field-div">
                    <table>
                        <tr style="white-space:nowrap;">
                            <td>
                                @Html.Action("PeoplePicker", "PeoplePicker", new EDAD.Models.PeoplePickerViewModel { PickerId = 30 })
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

                @*<span asp-validation-for="lobCoeCeNtId" class="text-danger"></span>*@
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Select Delegate 2</label>
                <div class="form-group form-field-div">
                    <table>
                        <tr style="white-space:nowrap;">
                            <td>
                                @Html.Action("PeoplePicker", "PeoplePicker", new EDAD.Models.PeoplePickerViewModel { PickerId = 40 })
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

                @*<span asp-validation-for="lobCoeCeNtId" class="text-danger"></span>*@
            </div>
 
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Here is the cshmtl for the People Picker (note that this is reusable so I don't want to modify any code in this)

```
@model ABC.Models.PeoplePickerViewModel

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        setUpGlyphicons(@Model.PickerId, '@Url.Action("SearchForUsers", "PeoplePicker")');
    });

</script>

<div class="people-picker">
    @Html.TextBox("UserResultTextbox_" + Model.PickerId, Model.User.userName, new { @onkeypress = "userSearchKeyPress(event);", @class = "form-control input-smaller", style = "display: inline", placeholder = "Last Name, First Name", autocomplete = "off" })
    @Html.Hidden("UserIdHidden_" + Model.PickerId, Model.User.NTId)
    @Html.Hidden("StoredUserNameHidden_" + Model.PickerId, Model.User.userName)
    @Html.Hidden("UserNameHidden_" + Model.PickerId, Model.User.userName)
    @Html.Hidden("UserEmailHidden_" + Model.PickerId, Model.User.userEmail)

    <span id="UserEditButton_@Model.PickerId" class="fa fa-pencil icon-inline"></span>
    <span id="UserCancelButton_@Model.PickerId" class="fas fa-ban hide icon-inline"></span>
    <span id="UserSearchButton_@Model.PickerId" class="fa fa-search hide icon-inline"></span>
    @*<span id="InjectButtonPlaceholder_@Model.PickerId" class="hide"></span>*@
    <img id="PeoplePickerLoading_@Model.PickerId" class="hide" alt="Loading..." src="~/Images/loading.gif" /><br />
    <span id="PeoplePickerError_@Model.PickerId" class="error-label">*</span>

    <div id="UserSearchContent_@Model.PickerId" class="list-group user-results"
         onmouseout="$('.disable-scroll-container').removeClass('disable-scroll');"
         onmouseover="$('.disable-scroll-container').addClass('disable-scroll');">
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I update the fields that start with the word "User" when the view fails validation

Comment: `I'd like the People Picker values to be retained as well, but since it is not part of the model` You can try to modify the approach to use a viewmodel that includes properties for original model and  People Picker related data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to close this question. I discovered that the issue lies in a different direction and I'm going to post a new question.